# defining mostly used class names

Tags: html, css

I have a silly question but while coding a web page I'm confuse a little time defining the css class name. Would anyone provide me `mostly used css class names` so that I could not hesitate while making pages.

It would be okay if I got mostly used class while layout page.

Comment: What should be the practical value of that answer (provided it's even answerable)? In any case, I guess the most used class names would be those auto-generated by various popular CMS.

Answer (score 1):

I think some css-naming-conventions will help :)

you may start here and search google for more :

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/

Comment: I need wrapper wrap like this, could you provide a link?

Comment: @Chapurlink sorry i didn't understand.. what exactly do u need?

Comment: while laying out page there is wrapper and wrap like this

Comment: Okay! See this link http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/really-beautiful-psd-web-templates/ could you please provide me how to define the classes of each part of POLO 360?

Comment: @Chapurlink aa got it! i think that you should name it by yourself, because you are the one developing it :)

there is no one-way-for-naming, you should find the best way that suits you.

and i think this can help you with css http://lesscss.org/ ..